# updating image source using jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

I'm trying to update my image source using jquery. To do it, I am calling `.load`

function that will return a string which in turn will be used to replace the image source.

`srcResult` value is `new/icon.png`:

```
<script>
 var iconLinkURL = "Users/NewIcon";
 var srcResult = $("#iconImage").children('img').load(iconLinkURL); 


  $("#iconImage").children('img').attr('src', srcResult);
</script>
```

HTML Side

```
<a id="iconImage"><img src="old/address.png"></img></a>
```

What happens is that when the javascript is loaded, the image is loaded like this:

```
 <a id="iconImage"><img src="[object Object]">new/icon.png</img></a>
```

Am I missing something hence the issue is persisting?

Comment: use $('').prop('src','url of image'');

Comment: `<img src="old/address.png"/>` not `<img src="old/address.png"></img>`

Answer (score 2):

`load()` returns an object. If you're not interested in pre-loading, just replace your code as follows:

```
$("#iconImage").children('img').prop('src', 'Users/NewIcon');
```

However, if you wish to preload the image, use the following:

```
var src = 'Users/NewIcon',
    img = new Image();

img.src = src;
img.onload = function() {
    $('#iconImage').children('img').prop('src', this.src);
};
```

It's worth noting that you will also need to wrap your code in the DOMReady event if you're not doing that already.